# Beautify PHP serialized strings

Tags: php, serialization, formatting

I'm serializing a large tree structure in PHP. Some of the data in the tree consists of objects which are referenced in multiple places. One bug I came across was where one of these objects was serialized twice. As you can imagine, after unserializing, writing data to one object would no longer update the other.

In an effort to detect problems like this, I have given each object a unique id. The problem with this approach is that, on a breakpoint, expanding and collapsing nodes is driving me crazy.

Does anybody know of a way I can beautify the output of `serialize`? Or some similar method? I'm looking for an XML type structure where everything is nested/indented.

Comment: have your tried `<pre> print_r(unserialize($serializedData)))</pre>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var_dump(unserialize($serializedData));
```

You may write a simple console program.

Comment: I tried that but the output contained ellipses after the first level in the tree. So most of the data was missing. Scratch that, http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php#82419 mentioned xDebug settings.

Comment: Ok. And how do you want to break that circular references? Btw, interesting question ;)